# Match the number of elements to the numbers in ArrayList

Tags: java

I have two arraylist, one is the numbers and another one is the number of elements.

For example:

Number of elements: [4, 3, 1]

Numbers: [31, 21, 50, 70, 90, 80, 50, 100]

```
for(Integer e : elements){

    for(Integer num : numbers){
       for (int i = 0; i < e; i++){
          System.out.print(num + " ");
       }
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

I want to match and print 4 elements to 4 numbers, 3 elements to the next 3 numbers and so on. How can print the numbers based on the index and the next numbers?

Output:

31 21 50 70

90 80 50

100

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to use the get method but it cannot find the symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
    {
        add(4);
        add(3);
        add(1);
    }
};

ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
    {
        add(31);
        add(21);
        add(50);
        add(70);
        add(90);
        add(80);
        add(50);
        add(100);

    }
};
for (Integer e : elements) {

    for (int i = count; i < count+e; i++) {
        System.out.print(numbers.get(i) + " ");
    }
    count += e;
    System.out.println();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the first1 and the loop over the 2 list according to the elements present in list 1.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> ele = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ele.add(4);
    ele.add(3);
    ele.add(1);

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(31);
    numbers.add(21);
    numbers.add(50);
    numbers.add(70);
    numbers.add(90);
    numbers.add(80);
    numbers.add(50);
    numbers.add(100);


    int k = 0,i=0,j=0;
    for(i = 0; i < ele.size(); i++){
        for(j = k ; j < k + ele.get(i); j++){
                System.out.print(numbers.get(j)+ " ");
        }
        k = j;
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Comment: To many loops.. the `numbers` could be iterate instead of accessed by index

Comment: @AxelH edit my answer if you have a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun, let's propose a solution for this small problem using :

```
List<Integer> elements = Arrays.asList(4,3,1);
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(31,21,50,70,90,80,50,100);
```

First, let's be sure we will not have any problem with index out of bounds with a simple check :

```
if (elements.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).sum() != numbers.size()){
    System.err.println("Invalid input");
    return;
}
```

Now, we just need an iterator for the numbers list :

```
Iterator<Integer> it = numbers.iterator();
```

And we iterate the elements as usual :

```
for(int n : elements){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        System.out.print(it.next() + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

There is no access outside of iterator with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will serve your purpose

```
List<Integer> element = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList(4, 3, 1));
List<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( 31, 21, 50, 70, 90, 80, 50, 100));
int cnt = 0;
for (Integer integer : element) {
    while (integer > 0) {
        System.out.print(number.get(cnt++));
        integer--;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

upvote if this answer is useful.